# What is the printing process of gold letter stationaries?

Tags: typography, print-design, lettering

I've been interested in designing stationaries, such as cards, envelopes, etc. I've seen many gold lettered stationaries, and am wondering how to print gold (luminescence) lettering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cheapest way to do it is with pantone gold. But that is only a avarage way to achieve gold. The real deal is to use «[Hot Stamping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_stamping)».

A heated die presses the gold-foil onto the stationary. Which results in a realy cool gold effect.

The downside of this are the costs because you need a separate die for every size. So if you have two products with two diffrent logo sizes. you already need two diffrent die's.

Comment: Is this something a person can do on his or her own, or is this something that will need to be sent to a printing company?

Comment: @AliBrunmeier I've never done it but I believe it's possible to do at home if you have a laminating machine. Look for foil laminating.